# In C program counting occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array. Mine counts the number of numbers instead of individual number counts?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

This first part defines the arrays and variables needed: `i` refers to rows, `j` refers to columns, `k` refers to the element in the array that stores number counts, and `l` refers to the number being tested, `c` and `d` are the user entries for the array size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int i, j, k, l;
    int c, d;
    printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array.\n");
    printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");
```

Here the array is created as the user specifies.

```
    scanf("%d %d", &c, &d);
    int charlesbarkley[c - 1][d - 1];
    int javariparker[9];
    for (j = 1; j <= d; j++) {
        printf("Enter row #%d #'s", j);

        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &charlesbarkley[i][j - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Here is four nested for loops that are designed to go to each element of the array (`charlesbarkely[i][j]`), test that element against numbers 0 - 9 incrementally (`l++`), then increment the individual array element (specified by `javariparker[k]`, `k` then increments) every time the user defined array element equals the incrementing value of `l` starting at 0.

```
    for (k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                for (l = 0; l <= 9; l++) {
                    if (charlesbarkley[i][j] != l)
                        javariparker[k] = javariparker[k];
                    else
                        javariparker[k] = (javariparker[k] + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to print the array with the number counts (0 - 9), but if my array is like 5x5 for example, it just spits 25 10 times back at me, so it's checking each element for every number instead of checking each element for just one number each time, how do i get this to work like I want it or am I going to a dead end?

```
    for (k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
        printf("%d", javariparker[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int charlesbarkley[c-1][d-1];` why `-1`? You are accessing the array out of bounds in the loop.

Comment: Number of numbers vs count of numbers? Hm.

Comment: If you declare an array like `int a[n];` The valid indices are `0 ...  n-1`. I think thats your problem here.

Comment: because the array starts at 0? if use enters 3X3 array, it has to be defined technically as charlesbarkley[2][2] cause three numbers lie in between 0 and 2 (0(1), 1(2), 2(3)), right?

Comment: and i am trying to count how many times certain numbers appear throughout the array

Comment: @steakfry Look at my other comment about valid indices.

Comment: how does that explain the output then?

Comment: the program compiles and the array is correct, it is the number counts that are the issue

Comment: and what should i chamger, just no [i-1][j-1], just [i][j], cause if i did that, the user entered size would always be 1 too many

Comment: @steakfry Because you never initialized the counter.

Comment: @steakfry Your whole program has undefined behaviour because you access the array out of bounds. There is no way to explain its output cause it is undefined how your program behaves. Strictly speaking it is not a valid C-program.

Comment: both arrays are out of bounds?

Comment: but it compiles and runs?

Comment: should i take a different approach altogether with the number counts?

Comment: its not out of bounds if it goes to charlesbarkley[0][0] i thought

Comment: the behavior is not undefined, it has logic to it

Comment: the way i see it at least

Comment: If you declare it like `int charlesbarkley[c - 1][d - 1];` then `charlesbarkley[c-1][d-1]` is out ouf bounds.

Comment: nvm i see lol   lol

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing your arrays out of bounds. If you declare an array like `int a[n];` the valid indices are `0 ... n-1`.

Using the counter variables uninitialized also invokes undefined behavior, you should initialize them with `int javariparker[10]={0};`:

You also do not need a fourth loop to count the occurrences.

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k, l; 
    int c, d;

    printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array.\n");
    printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");

    scanf("%d %d", &c, &d);
    int charlesbarkley[c][d];
    int javariparker[10]={0};

    for(j=0;j<d;j++)
    {
        printf("Enter row #%d #'s", j+1);

        for(i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&charlesbarkley[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(k=0;k<=9;k++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<d;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<c;i++)
            {
                if(charlesbarkley[i][j]==k)
                    javariparker[k]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(k=0;k<=9;k++)
    {
        printf("%d ",javariparker[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```